# Mixing past and present

Tags: present-tense

Recently I came across a sentence:

> Last week,my friend **asked** me how I **am** and I said (...).

To me this sounds completely wrong, as both happened in the past, I would expect it to be "how I ***was***" rather than "how I ***am***".

Is this reasoning correct or is my grammar knowledge incomplete?

Comment: Please site the source. Was it from a text book, Twitter, a novel etc.?

Comment: I can't find the exact URL, it was just a buzzfeed article, I think.

Comment: It's important to know the context. And it's important to know how the sentence ends.

Comment: Could this sentence be correct, given the friend did not ask about how she will be one week in the future?

Comment: Look up [**direct** and **indirect/reported speech**](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/123985/reported-speech-statements-whose-meaning-still-stands/123998#123998). It's difficult to answer your questions without knowing the full context

Comment: see also backshifting: [“He didn't know where New Jersey **was**”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/7964)

Comment: @Mari-LouA thank you very much, that was exactly what i was looking for

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of reported speech that has *not* been backshifted.

It is common and correct to "backshift" when changing from direct quote to reported speech.

> My friend asked me, "How are you?" (direct quote)
>
> My friend asked me how I was.  (correct and backshifted)

But while it is common, it is not a requirement for correct grammar:

> My friend asked me how I am.  (correct and not backshifted)